# Extracting dictionary items embedded in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say I have the following list of dict

```
t = [{'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0},
     {'a': 3.0, 'b': 4.0},
     {'a': 5.0, 'b': 6.0},
     {'a': 7.0, 'b': 9.0},
     {'a': 9.0, 'b': 0.0}]
```

Is there an efficient way to extract all the values contained in the dictionaries with a dictionary key value of `a`?

So far I have come up with the following solution

```
x = []
for j in t:
    x.append(j['a'])
```

However, I don't like to loop over items, and was looking at a nicer way to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
t = [{'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0},
 {'a': 3.0, 'b': 4.0},
 {'a': 5.0, 'b': 6.0},
 {'a': 7.0, 'b': 9.0},
 {'a': 9.0, 'b': 0.0}]
new_list = [i["a"] for i in t]
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0]
```

Since this solution uses a for-loop, you can use `map` instead:

```
x = list(map(lambda x: x["a"], t))
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0]
```

---

Performance-wise, you prefer to use list-comprehension solution rather the map one.

```
>>> timeit('new_list = [i["a"] for i in t]', setup='from __main__ import t', number=10000000)
4.318223718035199

>>> timeit('x = list(map(lambda x: x["a"], t))', setup='from __main__ import t', number=10000000)
16.243124993163093


def temp(p):
    return p['a']

>>> timeit('x = list(map(temp, t))', setup='from __main__ import t, temp', number=10000000)
16.048683850689343
```

There is a slightly difference when using a lambda or a regular function; however, the comprehension execution takes 1/4 of the time.

Comment: the `map` solution is really nice, is it preferable over the comprehension?

Comment: `list(map ...)` + `lambda` isn't better than the comprehension. When you have to use `lambda` in `map`, prefer the comprehension.

Comment: opt for list comprehension as it is optimized at implementation level

Comment: List comprehensions are considered more "Pythonic". They are usually easier to read than `map()`, and more efficient.

Comment: @Vinny in this case, list comprehension is faster because when using a map at each element of the list, a function (the lambda) must be defined.

Comment: @Ajax1234 gotcha. So the overhead of defining a function per iteration is the drawback. Would you say if we use regular function instead, both are equal efficiently?

Comment: @Vinny a `map` with a regular function (aka `def something():pass`) is actually faster than a list comprehension because the function `something` is previously declared.

Comment: @Ajax1234 I've tested it and apparently the comprehension solution wins by a big factor

Comment: @Vinny thank you for your edits. In this case, since map has a lambda function, the list comprehension is much better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

t = [{'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0},
     {'a': 3.0, 'b': 4.0},
     {'a': 5.0, 'b': 6.0},
     {'a': 7.0, 'b': 9.0},
     {'a': 9.0, 'b': 0.0}]

print map(itemgetter('a'), t)
```

result:

```
[1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension as suggested in [Ajax1234'a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448298/21945) answer, or even a generator expression if that would benefit your use case:

```
t = [{'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0}, {'a': 3.0, 'b': 4.0}, {'a': 5.0, 'b': 6.0}, {'a': 7.0, 'b': 9.0}, {'a': 9.0, 'b': 0.0}]
x = (item["a"] for item in t)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f0027def550>
```

The generator has the advantage of not executing or consuming memory until a value is needed. Use `next()` to take the next item from the generator, or iterate over it with a for loop.

```
>>> next(x)
1.0
>>> next(x)
3.0
>>> for n in x:
...     print(n)
5.0
7.0
9.0
```

---

An alternative, albeit a expensive one, is to use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame(t)['a'].tolist()
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0]
```